# Create and assign variables on Workbook_open, pass it to Worksheet_change

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a `Workbook_open` sub that creates `Long` variables when workbook is opened:

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()
  MsgBox ("Workbook opened")

  Dim i As Long
  i = 68 
End Sub
```

How would I pass the `i` value to a `Worksheet_change` sub for a particular worksheet?

Comment: If it's simply a static value why not just declare it within `Worksheet_change` instead?

Comment: Sorry, but I voted to close the answer under 'unclear what you're asking'. As of now, more details is required as to what exactly you're trying to achieve. Note: @Marcucciboy2 raises a very valid point there, but it's hard to answer, if we don't know what exactly you want to do

Comment: You might find this article on [Variable Scope](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/variable-scope.html) useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Dim i` inside a procedure scope makes `i` a *local* variable; it's only accessible from within the procedure it's declared in.

The idea of passing `i` to another procedure is very sound: it means you intend to keep variable scopes as tight as possible, and that's a very very good thing.

But in this case it's *too* tight, because the parameters of an event handler are provided by the event source: you need to "promote" that local variable up one scope level.

And the **next tightest scope** level is *module scope*.

You *can* use the `Dim` keyword at module level, but for consistency's sake I'd recommend using the keyword `Private` instead. So **in the same module**, declare your module-level variable:

```
Option Explicit
Private i As Long

Private Sub Workbook_open()
  MsgBox "Workbook opened"
  i = 68 
End Sub
```

If you want to expose that variable's value beyond this module, you can expose an *accessor* for it:

```
Option Explicit
Private i As Long

Private Sub Workbook_open()
  MsgBox "Workbook opened"
  i = 68 
End Sub

Public Property Get MyValue() As Long
'invoked when MyValue is on the right-hand side expression of an assignment,
'e.g. foo = ThisWorkbook.MyValue
    MyValue = i
End Property
```

Now the `Sheet1` module's `Worksheet_Change` handler can **read** it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.MyValue
End sub
```

But it can't **write** to it, because the property is "get-only". If everyone everywhere needs to be able to read/write to it, then you might as well make it a [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51899083/1188513), or expose a *mutator* for it:

```
Option Explicit
Private i As Long

Private Sub Workbook_open()
  MsgBox "Workbook opened"
  i = 68 
End Sub

Public Property Get MyValue() As Long
'invoked when MyValue is on the right-hand side expression of an assignment,
'e.g. foo = ThisWorkbook.MyValue
    MyValue = i
End Property

Public Property Let MyValue(ByVal value As Long)
'invoked when MyValue is on the left-hand side of an assignment,
'e.g. ThisWorkbook.MyValue = 42; the 'value' parameter is the result of the RHS expression
    i = value
End Property
```

Comment: didn't know about _"mutators"_.. fine discovery. and fine exposition

Comment: @DisplayName another name for them is "setter" (used in other languages), but the term "setter" just doesn't sit well in VBA, given `Property Set` and `Property Let` both exist (where `Property Set` is a mutator for an encapsulated object reference), and "letter" just doesn't quite cut it ;-)

Comment: aside from names, I didn't know about the possibility of giving/having `ThisWorkbook` members to set/let and get. I guess the code above is to reside in `ThisWorkbook` code pane, isn't it?

Comment: Yup. That said any module type can have properties, including standard module. `ThisWorkbook` is just a special kind of a class module - it's a *document* module which *inherits* all members of the `Workbook` class, and has a `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute (like a `UserForm` module) which makes its default instance globally accessible - so depending on whether you're referring to the *type* or the *object*, `ThisWorkbook` is either the module itself, or the *default instance of that class*, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

For that, declare `i` as a `Public Variable` on a `Standard Module` like `Module1` and then you can access the value of `i` in `Sheet Change Event` if it is `initialized` during `Workbook Open Event`.

**On Standard Module:**

```
Public i As Long
```

**On ThisWorkbook Module:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()
  MsgBox ("Workbook opened")
  i = 68
End Sub
```

Comment: Heaven help you when you've got 14 modules in your code and you're trying to figure out what `i` means and which one is being referenced (since everybody likes using `i` for loop indexes and other random, obscure purposes).

Comment: @FreeMan to be fair `i` is just OP's MCVE - I don't think anyone would make a global variable actually named `i` =)

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon Yeah, you are right. It was just an example. I actually am going to make that variable's name UNIQUE_AND_CLEAR.