# Public Variables in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

How do I declare 2 "Public" variables in the declaration section of "ThisWorkbook" so they are available across all modules after the worksheet is opened and until it is closed? Tried "Public WarningDate As Date, ExpirationDate As Date", but only the first, WarningDate, is available. Is there only 1 declaration line available? Can I list more than 1? If so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to provide more info. What code have you tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51899356/2727437

Comment: Hah, this is essentially the same query as the question posted immediately before yours (no answer yet, but I find it funny)

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables in object modules this way:

#### Worksheet module (say, Sheet1):

```
Public BigTime As Date, LittleTime As Date
```

#### Any module:

```
MsgBox Sheet1.BigTime
MsgBox Sheet1.LittleTime
```

Answer (score 0):

## Object Modules

It is not possible the way you're trying to do it.

You have to differentiate 'normal' **modules** (via add module) and **object** modules (ThisWorkbook, Sheet1, etc.).

If you declare a public variable in a 'normal' module, it will be 'visible' to all procedures of all modules including **object** modules as it is e.g.:

```
WarningDate
ExpirationDate
```

If you declare a public variable in an **object** module, it will be  'visible' to all procedures of the **object** module as it is e.g.:

```
WarningDate
ExpirationDate
```

and it will be 'visible' to all other modules including **object** modules, but you have to use its object reference to refer to it, e.g.:

```
ThisWorkbook.WarningDate
ThisWorkbook.ExpirationDate
```

**Conclusion**

You correctly declared the variables, but you didn't know how to refer to them. If you want public variables accessed without object references add (or pick) a **module** (**not object module**) and declare them there.

**Visualize**

```
' Code in ThisWorkbook
Option Explicit

Public ThisWorkbookDate As Date

Sub MainThisWorkbook()
  MsgBox ThisWorkbookDate
  MsgBox Module1Date
  MsgBox Sheet1.Sheet1Date
End Sub

' Code in Module1
Option Explicit

Public Module1Date As Date

Sub MainModule1()
  MsgBox ThisWorkbook.ThisWorkbookDate
  MsgBox Module1Date
  MsgBox Sheet1.Sheet1Date
End Sub

' Code in Sheet1
Option Explicit

Public Sheet1Date As Date

Sub MainThis() 'OK
  MsgBox ThisWorkbook.ThisWorkbookDate
  MsgBox Module1Date
  MsgBox Sheet1Date
End Sub
```

Comment: *If you declare a public variable in an object module it will only be 'visible' to all procedures in this module* What? If I declare `Public BigTime As Date` in `Sheet1`, I can call it in **any** module as `Sheet1.BigTime`.

Comment: @JohnyL: True, tested it. Sorry, will change the answer appropriately asap.

Comment: @JohnyL: I've found two sentences that are bothering me. 1. Variables declared using the Public statement are available to all procedures in all modules in all applications..., 2. Although Visual Basic permits loading of multiple projects, references between projects are never permitted in Visual Basic. What do they mean (Under 1 only the 'all applications' part)?

Comment: Where did you find this sentences? You *can* make variables shareable between projects, but it's a bit of hack. :)

Comment: @JohnyL: In Visual Basic Help: the first is in 'Public Statement' and the second one is the last sentence in 'Option Private Statement'. I was trying to access variables from another workbook, that's the reason I wrote my first stupid answer, 'cause I couldn't get it to work. It's not that I need the info, but I was just wondering.

Comment: As I mentioned, there's a dirty hack which would allow you to see another project's variables. It involves editing `cls` file. Just google it. 

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for the help. I ended up just placing the dates in a locked, hidden cell in the locked first worksheet, then referring to it in various macros and in an open workbook command. Each of these macros re-declares the variable with these cells values. Not the most efficient, but it works and I only need to update 3 cell dates to change the triggers.  The code I used is ...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

'Usage Rights Code
        Static WarningDate As Date
        WarningDate = Worksheets("XXX").Cells(1, 1).Value
        Static ExpirationDate As Date
        ExpirationDate = Worksheets("XXX").Cells(2, 1).Value
        Static LockDate As Date
        LockDate = Worksheets("XXX").Cells(3, 1).Value
        '
        If Date >= WarningDate And Date < ExpirationDate Then
            MsgBox "Usage rights for this workbook will expire on " _
                & ExpirationDate & ". After the expiration date, critical " _
                & "calculations will be disabled. Please contact ABC Co." _
                & "to avoid de-activation."
        ElseIf Date >= ExpirationDate And Date < LockDate Then
            MsgBox "Usage rights for this workbook expired on " _
                & ExpirationDate & ". Critical calculations have been " _
                & "disabled. The workbook will be locked on " & LockDate _
                & ". Please contact ABC Co. for re-activation."
        ElseIf Date >= LockDate Then
            MsgBox "Usage rights for this workbook expired on " _
                & ExpirationDate & ". The workbook has been disabled and " _
                & "locked. Please contact ABC Co. for re-activation."
            ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If

End Sub
```