# Public Property passing to other sheet modules

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script that uses a Private Sub Open_Workbook() to initialize some arrays from one of the excel sheets to be used as lookup tables later. The Private Sub Open_Worbook() is placed in the ThisWorkbook module and it appears to do it's job when the excel workbook is open.
The arrays in the Open_Workbook() sub are Dim as Variants but I have not been able to "pass" them along to Sheet1 for example to be used in the Sub for that sheet. I have tried using an accessor similar to what was suggested at the following link:
[Create and assign variables on Workbook_open, pass it to Worksheet_change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51898947/create-and-assign-variables-on-workbook-open-pass-it-to-worksheet-change)
Here is my code following that suggestion.
Following code is in the ThisWorkbook module of the excel workbook:

```
Option Explicit
Private Test_Array() As Variant

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
' Code here to redim preserve Test_array and set elements of the array and other code that 
' Added snippits of code to 
Dim Test_Array() As Variant
For i = 1 To UBound(TestRange,2)
     ReDim Preserve Test_Array(i - 1)
     Test_Array(i-1) = TestRange(1,i) 
Next i
End Sub 

Public Property Get TestArray() As Variant
    TestArray = Test_Array()
End Property
```

I was hoping that I would be able to use Thisworkbook.TestArray in Sheet1 to do some calculations on it but when I have a Msgbox ThisWorkbook.TestArray(0), I am getting a Subscript out of range error. I debugged the code and it appears that the Public Property Get TestArray(), Test_Array() is empty. What am I doing wrong? Can I not use Variant with Public Get Property?
I did confirm that the Test_Array in the Workbook_Open() Sub is indeed populated with the expected elements.

Edited: Added code for populating Test_Array

Comment: It would help if you show us the code that is "filling" `test_array()`.

Comment: Added code for filling Test_Array. Please note that the TestRange is not included in the code snippit. I have tested Test_Array and made sure it is properly populating as expected.

Comment: You have also declared `Test_Array` in Workbook_Open.  This is what you are filling but it is local to the Sub.  Your module level variable is not getting filled.  Remove this second declaration and you should be fine.

Comment: Remove Test_Array() declaration from the Private Sub Open_Workbook()? I did that but that did not change the results. When I call Msgbox(ThisWorkbook.TestArray(0)), I am still getting the same subscript out of range error.

Comment: Did you re-run Workbook_open? Did you check Test_Array in debug mode, when running Workbook_open?

Comment: Ahh, let me try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `Dim Test_Array() As Variant` on module level and in the `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`. **So** you **never** populate  `Test_Array` on the module level.

The following code is working for me

Workbook class module:

```
Option Explicit
Private Test_Array() As Variant

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
' Code here to redim preserve Test_array and set elements of the array and other code that
' Added snippits of code to
'Dim Test_Array() As Variant
Dim testrange
Dim i As Long
testrange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A4").Value
For i = 1 To UBound(testrange, 2)
     ReDim Preserve Test_Array(i - 1)
     Test_Array(i - 1) = testrange(1, i)
Next i
End Sub

Public Property Get TestArray() As Variant
    TestArray = Test_Array()
End Property
```

Normal module

```
 Option Explicit

Sub testit()
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.TestArray(0)
End Sub
```

Reading on [Lifetime of variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-the-lifetime-of-variables)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by I never populate Test_Array on the module level. I am populating it under Workbook_Open() so that it is initialized when the excel file is open. I am trying to use this Test_Array in one of the Sheet modules (Sheet1 for example).

Comment: What is not to understand? You have a variable definiton `Private Test_Array() As Variant` on module level and a variable definition `Dim Test_Array() As Variant` in the sub. Whenever you assign a value like`Test_Array(i - 1) = testrange(1, i)` in the sub it will only be assigned to the local variable in the sub.